# Como calcular promedio entre dos comisiones?

Tags: python

hola necesitaria saber en base a este codigo como puedo hacer para calcular cuál de
las dos es la comisión con mayor promedio:

```
def notas():

    suma=0
    cantidad_intentos=0
    notas_ingresadas=0
    validar = True

    while validar:
        notas_ingresadas=input('ingrese notas primera comision--[-1 para finalizar]: ')
        notas=int(notas_ingresadas)
        if (notas>=1 and notas<=10):
            suma=notas+suma
            cantidad_intentos=cantidad_intentos + 1
        elif (notas==-1):
            validar = False
        else:
            print('numero fuera de rango')

    promedio=(suma/cantidad_intentos)
    print("Nota promedio es: " + str(promedio))    

def notas1():
    suma=0
    cantidad_intentos=0
    notas_ingresadas1=0
    validar = True

    while validar:
        notas_ingresadas1=input('ingrese notas segunda comision[-1 para finalizar]: ')
        notas1=int(notas_ingresadas1)
        if (notas1>=1 and notas1<=10):
            suma=notas1+suma
            cantidad_intentos=cantidad_intentos + 1
        elif (notas1==-1):
            validar = False
        else:    
            print('numero fuera de rango')

    promedio1=(suma/cantidad_intentos)
    print("Nota promedio es: " + str(promedio1))  


notas()
notas1()
```

les comparto la consigna:
Se necesita un programa para realizar una comparación de la nota promedio
entre dos comisiones de la asignatura Introducción a la Programación. Para
esto, se le debe pedir al usuario que cargue una a una todas las notas de la
primera comisión, y una vez finalizadas, cargar una a una las de la segunda
comisión.
El programa debe informar en pantalla el promedio de cada comisión, y cuál de
las dos es la comisión con mayor promedio. Tenga en cuenta que no se conoce
de antemano la cantidad de alumnos de cada comisión, y las comisiones
pueden tener cantidades diferentes de alumnos.
Para indicar que ha terminado de cargar las notas de una comisión, el usuario
debe ingresar el valor -1. Si al ingresar una nota, la misma no es válida (es decir,
no está entre 1 y 10, y tampoco es -1), se le debe informar del error, y luego
continuar con la carga de notas normalmente, pero sin contabilizar la nota
inválida.

Comment: Cuál es el error en el código?

Comment: el codigo no tiene error me faltaria saber cual de las dos comisiones tiene mayor promedio y no se como hacerlo en el codigo?

Comment: Los valores almacenas en `promedio` y `promedio1`. Crea una función y trabaja con esos valores.

Comment: ya lo resolví gracias

Answer (score 1):

```
def notas(grupo):
    notas = [] # lista para guardar las notas
    nota = int(input("digite notas grupo {} digite -1 para finalizar: ".format(grupo)))
    while nota !=-1: # sentencia de corte
        if nota>=1 and nota<=10:
            notas.append(nota) # se almacena la nota 
        nota = int(input("digite notas grupo {} digite -1 para finalizar: ".format(grupo)))

    return sum(notas)/len(notas) # se calcula el promedio de las notas y se retorna el resultado

NotasGrupo1 = notas(1) # se envia el numero del grupo a cargar las notas y se conserva el retorno
NotasGrupo2 = notas(2) # se envia el numero del grupo a cargar las notas y se conserva el retorno

# seccion logica
if NotasGrupo1>NotasGrupo2:
    print("grupo 1 tuvo mejor promedio que grupo 2")
elif NotasGrupo2>NotasGrupo1:
    print("grupo 2 tuvo mejor promedio que grupo 1")
else:
    print("ambos grupos tuvieron el mismo promedio")
```